# Create list from csv lines in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file with 2 rows and multiple lines.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

     next(csv_reader)

     for row in csv_reader:
         print(row[0])
```

The output is:

```
row0line0
row0line1
row0line2
...
```

Is there a way i could further separate the rows into a list of individual cells?
Thanks

Comment: Are lines in different columns? Could you attach some portion of CSV file?

Comment: Could you show the expected result? If you just want a list, this should be enough: `lst = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]`.

Comment: What do you mean by a row with multiple lines? Do you mean that your CSV records span multiple lines? Are there fields that contain newline characters? Because if there aren’t fields with newline characters (that are enclosed in double quotes), each row is just a single line. If you have embedded newline characters, then you need to make sure the parser accepts them as part of the fields when they are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your csv file look like this:

```
row0line0
row1line1
...
```

If its possible i should reccomand to change it to:

```
row0 line0
row1 line1
...
```

(Add a space between the rows and the lines)

Then you can update your code to the code bellow to print only the rows and create two lists - one that contain the rows and another that contain the lines:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

next(csv_reader)
rows = []
lines = []
for item in csv_reader:
    temp = item[0].split(" ")
    rows.append(temp[0])
    lines.append(temp[1])
    print(temp[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that each row becomes an element of the list that goes this way:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    data_list = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

Otherwise, if you want to create a list of the first elements of each line, you can do this:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    row0_list = []
    for row in reader:
      row0_list.append(row[0])
```

I hope the problem is solved with this explanation.

Comment: I already have a list of the rows (row[0], row[1]), each of them contain cells. What i would like to do is get a list of the cells inside a specific row. This way i could first select the row and then the the cell inside that row.

Comment: row[i] will already get you the list of cells for a specific row. What other information are you asking for? Look at my answer and see what is printed out when you do print(row). What other information are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are asking to output all the data fields. csv_reader is already separating your rows into a list individual cells!

You current script reads the file one line at a time and prints the first item in each row with this line:

```
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row[0])
```

Instead of printing row[0], which only prints the first field in the csv row, you can just print the row:

```
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

That will output the field lists (from my sample csv):

```
['r0v0', 'r0v1', 'r0v2']
['r1v0', 'r1v1', 'r1v2']
```

If you want to print in a nicer format, you can use join:

```
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(", ".join(row))
```

Output:

```
r0v0, r0v1, r0v2
r1v0, r1v1, r1v2
```

My csv:

```
r0v0,r0v1,r0v2
r1v0,r1v1,r1v2
```